# Program type already present: tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.AbstractMediaPlayer

Tags: android, gradle, transitive-dependency, ijkplayer

I have defined below gradles in my app.gradle

```
 implementation 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.8.8'
 implementation 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-armv7a:0.8.8'
```

and also defined same in one of the module integrated.

When I try to run the code it throws error as below

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present:
>   tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.AbstractMediaPlayer","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Comment: post full Gradle.

Comment: I don't think it requires full gradle to be posted.